# Plotly Express LaTeX in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly, latex

I can't typeset a Plotly Express label with [LaTeX style](https://plotly.com/python/LaTeX/) using VS Code.
It just shows the string as is.
Example:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.density_heatmap(df, x="x", y="y", z="z", title="$x^2$")
```

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions to install and use [mathjax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src#installation-and-use)?